# Laravel relationship query with 'LIKE' issue

Tags: laravel, relationship

I've got following LARAVEL self relationship on User model:

```
public function matchesSet(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'matches', 'user_id', 'match_id')->withPivot('confirmed');
}
```

Then I run:

```
User::first()->matchesSet->where('pivot.confirmed', true)->where('name','LIKE', 'John')->count()
```

or

```
User::first()->matchesSet->where('pivot.confirmed', true)->where('name','John')->count()
```

and I get the expected result: "1" in this case.

BUT if I add % to the LIKE query, in any of this variants:

```
User::first()->matchesSet->where('pivot.confirmed', true)->where('name','LIKE', '%John%')->count()
```

```
User::first()->matchesSet->where('pivot.confirmed', true)->where('name','LIKE', '%{John}%')->count()
```

```
User::first()->matchesSet->where('pivot.confirmed', true)->where('name','LIKE', "%John%")->count()
```

```
User::first()->matchesSet->where('pivot.confirmed', true)->where('name','LIKE', "%{John}%")->count()
```

then I get wrong result, in all cases: "0".

What's wrong with my LIKE queries?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `matchesSet` as a function to trigger a query and use `wherePivot` to query the pivot attribute:

```php
User::first()->matchesSet()->wherePivot('confirmed', true)->where('name', 'like', '%John%')->count();
```

Otherwise, you are simply referring to the `where` function of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

For more information, look under **Filtering Relationships Via Intermediate Table Columns**: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: ok. You'r right, it works when I
User::first()->matchesSet()->where('name', 'like', '%John%')->count();

But if I call matchesSet() as a function, then I can't query my pivot table (i have to remove where('pivot.confirmed',true) clause.

What am I missing?

Comment: @JoanT You need to use `->wherePivot`. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Chin Leung!!! It works!!

I have voted you answer but I'm such a rookie in stackoverflow and it doesn't publish my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$q = 'John'
User::first()
->matchesSet
->where('pivot.confirmed', true)
->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')->count()
```

Comment: No. Converting it into a variable does not make any difference. Thank you for your answer, but the good one is Chin Leung's.

Comment: This is no different from the first example in @JoanT's attempt. You simply moved the `John` into a variable. It does not solve the problem at all.